# Installing utils (NOT python-utils) in a conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda, pypi

How do I install utils (https://pypi.org/project/utils/) in a conda environment?
Not python-utils (https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/)
Usually I search for a module by

```
conda search utils
```

and then install it using

```
conda install utils
```

But looks like utils isnt there in conda.

There is something called python-utils though, it looks like a different package.

Answer (score 3):

Install conda-related `pip` and use `pip` to install packages from PyPI to your conda environments:

```
conda install pip
pip install utils
```